# Running goal seek or solver entirely within VBA form

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run an iterative calculation automatically in excel using goalseek or solver. I've done this before, and have made them run automatically based on a sheet change event on a specific cell, etc. However this time I want this to run entirely in a VBA form. At the moment the input will be "Presscalc2", which is shown as a variable here. In a perfect world a change to a textbox would store the variable for "Presscalc2", and then round the subroutine. This is the code I have:

```
Private Sub TextBox13_AfterUpdate()

PressCalc2 = TextBox13
Call RunSteamTemp

End Sub

Private Sub RunSteamTemp()

Dim a1 As Double
Dim a2 As Double
Dim a3 As Double
Dim a4 As Double
Dim a5 As Double
Dim a6 As Double
Dim Tc As Double
Dim Pc As Double
Dim Rc As Double
Dim T As Double

a1 = -7.859517823
a2 = 1.84408259
a3 = -11.7866479
a4 = 22.6807411
a5 = -15.9618719
a6 = 1.80122502
Tc = 647.096
Pc = 22.064
Rc = 322

tau = 1 - (T / Tc)

Goalseekval1 = Log(PressCalc2 / Pc) - (Tc / (T + 0.0000001)) * (a1 * tau + a2 * tau ^ 1.5 + a3 * tau ^ 3 + a4 * tau ^ 3.5 + a5 * tau ^ 5 + a6 * tau ^ 7.5)

On Error Resume Next
Dim bSuccess As Boolean

bSuccess = Goalseekval1.GoalSeek(0, T)
If Not bSuccess Then MsgBox "TSAT Error"

TempCalc2 = T * (9 / 5) - 459.67

Label24 = TempCalc2

End Sub
```

Most of this is defining variables, and I don't think the equation has any errors. The goal is to set "Goalseekval1" to 0 by changing "T". All it gives me now is an error though. I've also tried running it with a command button rather than the AfterUpdate action, but had the same result. Any help would be appreciated. The examples I've  found online are designed to run this based off of a cell in a worksheet, but in this case the input values and any action would be based on a textbox afterupdate change (ideally).

Thank you,

Craig

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I get the "TSAT Error" which is set to run when it's unsuccessful. The "PressCalc2" value is being stored as a variable properly, Label24 outputs -459.67, indicating "T" remained 0.

I've also seen this written as:

Goalseekval1.GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=T

This doesn't work either (I get a Runtime Error 424).

Comment: Remove (or comment out) `On Error Resume Next` and see what error you get.  What's the `TSAT Error`?

Comment: I get the same 424 error. "TSAT Error" was a warning that ran to indicate that the calculation for saturated steam temp failed. This doesn't necessarily have to be goalseek, but I don't know what other iterative methods can run on VBA. The problem is that "T" cannot be solved for explicitly, so it has to be solved numerically.

Comment: You don't set any value for `T` so `tau = 1 - (T / Tc)` will always be =1. With goal seek, you kinda want to work with ranges as in `Range().GoalSeek(value,Range())` and in your code `Goalseekval1` is not a range nor is `T` so no chance for it to work. I would transfer the variables in a spreadsheet including the formula and then use the "classic" Goal Seek. VBA is not helping for anything in your example except for the error message thing.

Comment: I was hoping to run this entirely in VBA and only ever export to a cell. I tried with subbing (1-(T/Tc)) for every instance of tau which made the equation long as heck, but also helped to constrain T inside the equation only.  Is goalseek only designed to run from ranges in a spreadsheet? The idea is that this will be a calculation dialogue that pops up and can then export to a print area.

Comment: Would a while loop accomplish this? I'm trying to iterate "T" until "Goalseekval1" is zero, so if there's a way to do that I don't need goalseek.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can find more efficient code for this but I came up with the following :

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub RunSteamTemp_Main()

Dim K As Double: K = 5 'Change this back to your input value PressCalc2
Dim T As Double: T = 1
Dim Target_Val As Double: Target_Val = 0
Dim Test_Val As Double
Dim Step_Val As Double: Step_Val = 0.001 'Play with this to increase accuracy
Dim Max_It As Long: Max_It = 1000000 'This limits the infinite loop case
Dim i As Long

If Abs(RunSteamTemp(T - 0.01, K) - Target_Val) > Abs(RunSteamTemp(T + 0.01, K) - Target_Val) Then Step_Val = Step_Val * -1

For i = 1 To Max_It
    Test_Val = RunSteamTemp(T, K)
    If Abs(Test_Val - Target_Val) < 0.001 Then 'where 0.001 is your error spread acceptation
        Debug.Print T, Format(Test_Val, "0.0000") 'Change this to define what you want to do with the result
        Exit Sub
    Else
        T = T + Step_Val
    End If
Next i

Debug.Print "No results close enough"

End Sub

Private Function RunSteamTemp(T, K)

Dim a1 As Double: a1 = -7.859517823
Dim a2 As Double: a2 = 1.84408259
Dim a3 As Double: a3 = -11.7866479
Dim a4 As Double: a4 = 22.6807411
Dim a5 As Double: a5 = -15.9618719
Dim a6 As Double: a6 = 1.80122502
Dim Tc As Double: Tc = 647.096
Dim Pc As Double: Pc = 22.064
Dim Rc As Double: Rc = 322 'This is not used ?

RunSteamTemp = Log(K / Pc) - (Tc / (T + 0.0000001)) * (a1 * (1 - (T / Tc)) + a2 * (1 - (T / Tc)) ^ 1.5 + a3 * (1 - (T / Tc)) ^ 3 + a4 * (1 - (T / Tc)) ^ 3.5 + a5 * (1 - (T / Tc)) ^ 5 + a6 * (1 - (T / Tc)) ^ 7.5)

End Function
```

And it's giving me acceptable results.

Comment: Thanks so much O.PAL for putting in the work on this, I'll test it out this afternoon and let you know what happens.

Comment: I'm getting a compile error that the function isn't found. I created a module and put it in that, but I'm not sure that was the right approach. I'm fairly new to programming so sorry if I sound clueless.

Comment: I've got it working - Thanks so much for your help. now I just need to figure out how to define "T" as an output for use elsewhere in the sheet, but that shouldn't be too hard. By the way the "*-1" after "Step_Val" was causing issues, getting rid of that allowed it to run properly. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

In my previous answer I was trying to first find the orientation to be sure not to drift further away from 0. But it seems this is not needed with your formula so here is an updated faster code with more accurate results :

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub RunSteamTemp_Main()

Dim K As Double: K = 20 'Change this back to your input value PressCalc2
Dim T As Double: T = 0
Dim Target_Val As Double: Target_Val = 0
Dim Test_Val As Double
Dim Step_Val As Double: Step_Val = 0.1
Dim Max_It As Long: Max_It = 10000 'This limits the infinite loop case
Dim Max_i As Long: Max_i = 10 'Increase this to increase accuracy
Dim i As Long, j As Long

For i = 1 To Max_i
    For j = 1 To Max_It
        Test_Val = RunSteamTemp(T, K)
        If Test_Val < 0 Then
            T = T - Step_Val ^ i
            Exit For
        Else
            T = T + Step_Val ^ i
        End If
    Next j
Next i

T = (T - Step_Val ^ Max_i) * (9 / 5) - 459.67

'From here you can use the T as you wish : range("A1")=T , msgbox T , debug.print T ...
Debug.Print T

End Sub

Private Function RunSteamTemp(T, K)

Dim a1 As Double: a1 = -7.859517823
Dim a2 As Double: a2 = 1.84408259
Dim a3 As Double: a3 = -11.7866479
Dim a4 As Double: a4 = 22.6807411
Dim a5 As Double: a5 = -15.9618719
Dim a6 As Double: a6 = 1.80122502
Dim Tc As Double: Tc = 647.096
Dim Pc As Double: Pc = 22.064
Dim Rc As Double: Rc = 322 'This is still not used ?

RunSteamTemp = Log(K / Pc) - (Tc / (T + 0.0000001)) * (a1 * (1 - (T / Tc)) + a2 * (1 - (T / Tc)) ^ 1.5 + a3 * (1 - (T / Tc)) ^ 3 + a4 * (1 - (T / Tc)) ^ 3.5 + a5 * (1 - (T / Tc)) ^ 5 + a6 * (1 - (T / Tc)) ^ 7.5)

End Function
```

Comment: I finally got a chance to integrate this into the program - It does work well and seems to have less processing overhead. Thank you again! I'm going to work on disecting this to figure out how it works. :)